# Histogramns of the data grouped by month

Tags: r, histogram

If I would like to aggregate the data by month, an approach is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(2017)
options(digits=4)

(expenses <- data_frame(
   date=seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by=1),
   amount=rgamma(length(date), shape = 2, scale = 20)))
```

Then I summarized them by month like this:

```
expenses %>% group_by(month=floor_date(date, "month")) %>%
summarize(amount=sum(amount))
```

I would like to plot an histogram of the variable `amount` for each month. How could I do it?

Comment: @RonakShah: thank you but no, I would like to obtain different histograms, one for each month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the month value from `date` and using facets you can show histogram for every month in separate plots.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

expenses %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(month = format(date, '%b %Y'), 
         month = factor(month, unique(month))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(amount) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) + 
  facet_wrap(~month)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to change the scale of y axis for each of the plots? In another example I have very different scale from a month to another.

Comment: Yep. You can use `facet_wrap(~month, scales = 'free')` to have independent x and y-axis in each plot or `'free_y'` to have independent y-axis and same with `'free_x'`.

Comment: Thanks again, I upvoted your answer. A last thing, if possible: is it possible to group the data by quarters or semesters, instead by months?

Comment: Sure, you need to extract the quarters from the date. `quarter = as.character(zoo::as.yearqtr(date))` and change all the reference of `month` to `quarter` in the above code. I am not sure what is a semester but I am sure there must be a similar way to get semester from date.